# Get the message after eval and not message + line number + file name

Tags: perl, error-handling, eval

I have a cgi perl script composed of a model and a controller

```
#controller.cgi
use model qw(may_corak_function); 
...
eval {
    may_croak_funtion( $my_arg )
} 
if ($@) {
    print "Failed because $@";
}
```

And, in a secret place is defined the model :

```
#model.pm
package model;
use Carp qw(croak); 
sub may_croak_function {
     my $p = shift;
     if ($p eq 'not this') {
          croak "$p is not accepted";
}
```

Well, I get the error message

```
Failed because not this is not accepted at /secret/path/model.pm line 81
```

As I do not want some perl script output all the server configuration as soon as an error is risen how can I get only the message without `at /secret/path/model.pm at line 81`?

I have browse the Internet and I cannot believe how nobody else have the same obvious problemè

Comment: Add a newline to the message.